# Plotting a broom/light source

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, rotation

Im trying to create a broom-like figure in MATLAB like illusrated here:

[image: Broom plot]

My idea was start off with the horizontal line and then using a rotation matrix within a loop create the others. However my code seems to be playing tricks on me.

In a nutshell I want to create lines spreading out from a specific point with with the same angle between each and every line.

This is my code so far.

```
th = pi/12; % 15 degrees between every line
pointA = [20 50]; %The starting point of every line
pointB = [90 50]; %The ending point of the center line
v = [pointA(1) pointB(1); pointA(2) pointB(2)];
%
R =@(x)[cos(x) -sin(x); sin(x) cos(x)]; % Rotation matrix function
%
for i = -4:4
   c = R(i*th)*v;
   line([pointA(1) c(1,2)],[pointA(2) c(2,2)]);
   hold on
end
```

Any ideas why the angles on the lines (except the center line) are off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a rotation matrix always rotates around the origin (`[0,0]`), but you want it to rotate around `pointA`. The solution is either to

1. generate the lines with the necessary angle and length, and displace them by `pointA`, or
2. shift 2d space such that `pointA` becomes the origin, do the rotation, and shift the points back.

I would find the latter approach straightforward, since your pre-rotation end points are naturally defined:

```
th = pi/12; % 15 degrees between every line
% pointA and pointB must be column vectors for matrix multiplication later
pointA = [20; 50]; %The starting point of every line
pointB = [90; 50]; %The ending point of the center line
%
R = @(x)[cos(x) -sin(x); sin(x) cos(x)]; % Rotation matrix function
%
hold on;    % Hold on and off around loop to plot all lines on same fig
for i = -4:4
   % line is initially pointA -> pointB
   % shift the world by -point A
   % line is now [0,0] -> pointB-pointA
   % rotate the world around the origin
   % line is now [0,0] -> R*(pointB-pointA)
   % shift the world back
   % line is now pointA -> R*(pointB-pointA) + pointA
   c = R(i*th)*(pointB-pointA) + pointA;
   % note that c is now a single 2d vector: image of pointB
   line([pointA(1) c(1)],[pointA(2) c(2)]);
end
hold off;
```